# How to write this jquery string in pure javascript (in my online store)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reworking some code from jQuery to pure javascript, i have reworked everything i wanted except one string. How to write this jquery string in pure javascript? I marked the string with a comment.

```
var cart = {}; 

$.getJSON('goods.json', function (data) {
    var goods = data; 
    checkCart();
   showCart(); 

    function showCart() {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(cart)) { /*--------THIS STRING------ */  
            var out = 'The cart is empty. Add product to cart <a href="index.html">главная страница</a>';
            document.getElementById('my-cart').innerHTML = out;
        }
        else {
            var out = '';
            for (var key in cart) {
                out += '<button class="delete" data-art="' +  key  + '" > x </button>';
                out += ' <img src="' + goods[key].image + '" width="48">';
                out += goods[key].name;
                out += ' <button class="minus" data-art="' +  key  + '"> - </button>';
                out += cart[key];
                out += ' <button class="plus" data-art="' +  key  + '"> + </button>';
                out += cart[key] * goods[key].cost;
                out += '<br>';
            }
            document.getElementById('my-cart').innerHTML = out;                          
            document.querySelectorAll('.plus').forEach(function(but) {
            but.addEventListener("click",plusGoods);
})  
            document.querySelectorAll('.minus').forEach(function(but) {
           but.addEventListener("click",minusGoods);
})    
            document.querySelectorAll('.delete').forEach(function(but) {
           but.addEventListener("click",deleteGoods);
})    
        }
    }
```

Also I will just write the code continuation just in case you may need it for a comprehensive understanding of the code:

```
    function plusGoods() {
         var articul = this.getAttribute('data-art');       
        cart[articul]++;
        saveCartToLS(); 
        showCart();
    }

    function minusGoods() {
         var articul = this.getAttribute('data-art');      
        if (cart[articul] > 1) {
            cart[articul]--;
        }
        else {
            delete cart[articul];
        }
        saveCartToLS();
        showCart();
    }

    function deleteGoods() {
          var articul = this.getAttribute('data-art');      
        delete cart[articul];
        saveCartToLS();
        showCart();
    }
});

function checkCart() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart') != null) {
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    }
}

function saveCartToLS() {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
}
```

I ask you to help translate this string

Comment: What "query string"? The marked line has no string constants in it at all.

Comment: Do you want to replace the `$.isEmptyObject(cart)` call ?

Comment: you also have to replace `$.getJSON` by a fetch... but  why did you show us so much code for just 1 line ?

Comment: For reference I'd call that a "jQuery method call" (or maybe "jQuery utility method call"); the term "query string" usually means a CSS selector string that you'd pass to the `$()` function to search the DOM.

Comment: Yes, I want replace the $.isEmptyObject(cart) call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for ... in` to iterate through all enumerable properties. If the object is empty (i.e. does not contain any enumerable properties) there shouldn't be an iteration at all:

```
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
  for (var name in obj) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

BTW: This is exactly [how it's done in jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/30e1bfbdcb0ff658f1fa128b72480194e8ecb926/src/core.js#L228).

Comment: but how to implement it in my code? I just started learning in js, then I don't know how to build it properly.

Comment: Put the code posted in the answer somewhere in your code (e.g. next to one of your other functions like `checkCart`) and then replace `$.isEmptyObject(cart)` with `isEmptyObject(cart)`

Comment: but i have in "if" body:
 ```var out = 'The cart is empty. Add product to cart <a href="index.html">главная страница</a>';
document.getElementById('my-cart').innerHTML = out;```
and in "else" i have some body. 
but in your code instead of the body of my code - "return false" and "return true".
Can you combine my code and what you wrote? Because I don't understand

Comment: You don't need to touch any code in the if/else bodies. Just replace `$.isEmptyObject(cart)` with `isEmptyObject(cart)`. No need to change any other code.